# Newly gained Access Token from social login is resulting in This session is not valid for use with the REST API error for api requests

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I am using Django-allauth for social logins. I confirmed that I have the access token that I receive from salesforce after the social login, but when I do

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}
```

in my rest api call, it didn't work. When I paste the same token into postman, I am getting an INVALID SESSION ID error. In my connected app, I set the token expiry to 30 minutes. This happens to newly generated token too. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, _Complete_ and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.